# Creating symbolic link in RASPBIAN (reduce I/Os on memory card)

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, pi-3b+, logfiles

I'm doing this to reduce I/Os on memory card of raspberry pi. I want to redirect logs under /var/log to a mounted external drive. I am using following commands in the stated order to create the links. There are 2 solutions i'm exploring.

**Method: 1**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rsyslog stop
ln -fs /var/log/messages 
/path/to/mount/messages
sudo /etc/init.d/rsyslog stop
```

I have removed files in case this doesn't work using `rm` command. My primary problem is reboot and remounting of drives. Whenever I reboot the RPi I need to mount the drives again. However, the logs start getting written to `/var/log` and I have to go through the trial and error process again. I have edited logging path in software's wherever possible. However for system processes and logs such as `messages, mail, wtmp, debug` i am unable to find a solution.

What is the most robust way to ensure I log on the external drive all the time. /mnt/path/ all the time? including for system applications?

**Method 2:**

This  is where I mount my external device to /var/log folder using `fstab`. I've taken a backup of my fstab file using `sudo cp -p /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.17.11.2018`

Following is what the file contents are:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=dd5ad381-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=dd5ad381-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

Following is the output of `blkid`

```
user@hostname:~# sudo blkid
/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL="boot" UUID="FBD8-71DF" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="dd5ad381-01"
/dev/mmcblk0p2: LABEL="rootfs" UUID="e9646bf0-ef1f-4e8b-983b-c9f97f60e931" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="dd5ad381-02"
/dev/mmcblk0: PTUUID="dd5ad381" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="logs" UUID="50043501-276b-473d-a6a5-bda12a845d67" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="1068b060-01"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="label" UUID="f1da78dc-d69b-4902-9646-f1719b637634" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="part-label" PARTUUID="f8a547cb-9870-49ee-8055-70f7ff025926"
```

The current directory I mount the sdb1 is /mnt/logs. I am ok changing this. How should my line for the logs file should look like? Is the following correct?

```
PARTUUID=1068b060-01 /var/logs ext4 sync,auto,nodev,noexec,suid,rw,nouser, 0 2
```

I wanted to run this by the community given the sensitivity of the operation. I was reading the man page at (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab#Device). I am not sure but can I lock down the mount for only administrator? I don't see a log file that is for anyone but the root anyway.

Following is the content of /etc/rsyslog.conf file. I've tried doing this but it doesn't work too. **Is it because I've created symbolic links?**

```
user@hostname:~ $ cat /etc/rsyslog.conf
#  /etc/rsyslog.conf    Configuration file for rsyslog.
#
#                       For more information see
#                       /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/rsyslog_conf.html


#################
#### MODULES ####
#################

module(load="imuxsock") # provides support for local system logging
module(load="imklog")   # provides kernel logging support
#module(load="immark")  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# provides UDP syslog reception
#module(load="imudp")
#input(type="imudp" port="514")

# provides TCP syslog reception
#module(load="imtcp")
#input(type="imtcp" port="514")


###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################

#
# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
#
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

#
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileOwner root
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022

#
# Where to place spool and state files
#
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

#
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
#
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf


###############
#### RULES ####
###############

#
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
#
auth,authpriv.*                 /mnt/logs/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/mnt/logs/syslog
#cron.*                         /mnt/logs/cron.log
daemon.*                        -/mnt/logs/daemon.log
kern.*                          -/mnt/logs/kern.log
lpr.*                           -/mnt/logs/lpr.log
mail.*                          -/mnt/logs/mail.log
user.*                          -/var/log/user.log

#
# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
#
mail.info                       -/var/log/mail.info
mail.warn                       -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err                        /var/log/mail.err

#
# Some "catch-all" log files.
#
*.=debug;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        news.none;mail.none     -/var/log/debug
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        cron,daemon.none;\
        mail,news.none          -/var/log/messages

#
# Emergencies are sent to everybody logged in.
#
*.emerg                         :omusrmsg:*
```

The reason of doing this is because I'm running a web server on my RPi and the logs are in excess of 2 GB a day.

Comment: *"I'm running a web server on my RPi and the logs are in excess of 2 GB a day."* -> Unless you have a web server which is logging to syslog (which is a very bad strategy), this is not a good explanation in of why the system logs are that way.  I've worked on servers with more traffic than a Pi could possibly handle and they do not generate anything close to that...  **Put another way, you have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479).**

Comment: How do I find out if Apache2 has configuration pointing to syslog for it's logging. There are individual configuration lines within Apache2 which I've pointed to the external drive. I do have other solutions such as ModSecurity (WAF) which add to logging file size. I would love to understand and optimize my logging while ensuring security details are successfully logged.

Comment: It sounds like you have a lot of reading to do about your software.  I'll give you my $0.02:  Put the logs on the HD at least for now, but try and figure out what all that stuff is and whether it is really necessary.  If you put 5 Mbps through the little thing *constantly*, in 24 hrs that's ~53 GiB of information -- and somehow at that rate you've generated 5% of that volume *going through syslog*, the logger is being used for something special.  If it is security stuff, you should be redirecting all of it.

Comment: I haven't made any changes to default configuration. So I am not sure for the "noise". I have changed logging on the WAF (modsecurity) to log all responses. However, this is only for ModSec. I have a problem wherein the logs are now going to the HDD but they can be accessed (`cat` syslog) by any user. permissions for the file are **-rw-r----- 1 root adm** .. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I forgot to mention the "catch-all" files mentioned in the configuration too.  If a lot of those messages are actual warnings (they have numerical priorities), `/var/log/messages` will get quite big.  If not you could leave it as is so you will get error messages saved if, e.g., the hard drive fails to mount or something.

Comment: WRT permissions on the log in the mounted partition, that sounds strange.  Are *all* the files there like that?  Is it really an ext4 filesystem as in the question?

Comment: Yes it is. I was just about to message you. Somehow in my clumsiness of not keeping a good changelog - the system seems to be broken. Log files are readable without root. I am thinking of formatting and starting over. I will keep you posted. What is important is that this RPi will server as a personal cloud server running nextcloud (www.nextcloud.com) and will hold my family's data. I need to make it robust. Reducing I/O on the memory card was a decision based on keeping the OS running longer. I am storing the data on a HDD (cloud data). I will swap with a new card and see if that works.

Comment: Even if the swapping of card works, it will have some challenges as I'll have to test a day old (time does not matter) card with the DB of the cloud software that stores the data. There is bound to be an integrity check and it may not let me restore service if backup copy of the memory card has older DB. I will keep you posted on this too. This is one of my papers as part of  my MSc in systems and software security. :) I appreciate your responses and have a wonderful week ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following if the final configuration that fulfills all my requirement.

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
#note the UUID
#make backup of your  fstab file. I add date and time to name of any file to make it a backup file. You can do something different such as .backup
sudo cp -p /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.25.11.2018.1425
sudo nano /etc/fstab
#Add the line UUID=bca6c466-d4aa-44b8-9696-a11b610ec47c /mnt/1/ ext4    auto,noexec,rw,sync,nouser,nosuid,nofail    0   2
#you can read about the options I've added here - https://wiki.debian.org/fstab
#now to move the logging configuration to the new folder. Please keep in mind, you will have to do this for all the application(s) you have. My configuraiton is for the system and UFW (firewall).
#first stop the rsyslog sevice
sudo /etc/init.d/rsyslog stop
#backup the rsyslog coniguration
sudo cp -p /etc/rsyslog.conf /etc/rsyslog.conf.24.11.2018.2249
#edit the file
Sudo nano /etc/rsyslog.conf
#edit the directories to your mount point for me it is /mnt/1
#edit the UFW configuration
cd /etc/rsyslog.d
#backup the file
sudo cp -p 20-ufw.conf 20-ufw.conf.25.11.2018.1434
#edit the file
sudo nano 20-ufw.conf
#point the log files to your mount point (folder)
# start the service again
sudo /etc/init.d/rsyslog start


To check the configuraiton reboot your pi
sudo reboot now
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I've pointed out elsewhere [the motivation here is misguided](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84902/pimp-rsyslogd-to-have-less-i-o-cron-pam-and-less-logging/84905#84905), a simpler way to do this is to just change the `rsyslog` configuration.  Here's a section of the default `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
#
auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
#cron.*                         /var/log/cron.log
daemon.*                        -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.*                           -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log
user.*                          -/var/log/user.log
```

You will similarly want to deal with the entries under `"catch-all" log files` below this in the configuration file.

You can change those paths then `sudo systemctl restart syslog`.  Rsyslog has been around for a long time (a decade more than the Pi), and the syslog protocol (of which it implements a superset of features) decades more than that, so you should easily be able to fine lots of documentation online and on the system if you are interested. Rsyslog also has an HTML doc package, but `man rsyslog.conf` is best place to start.

There may or may not be boot issues for you this way; make sure the partition is automounted in `/etc/fstab`.

> Is the following correct?
>
> ```
> PARTUUID=1068b060-01 /var/logs ext4 sync,auto,nodev,noexec,suid,rw,nouser, 0 2
> ```

You may want `noatime` in there too, depending on how you feel about saving wear on the drive ;P and how important getting access times is to you.  But that should work.  Maybe the last field should be `3`, I think those should be unique (probably better would be to make the boot partition `3` and this one `2`).

A problem with symlinking the files is that these files are periodically rotated.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for replying. I am fairly certain I've read your thread because this is what my rsyslog.conf file looks like. I've edited my question to include the output of the config file. Is creating symbolic links and editing the configuration file causing problem and not logging on the external drive?

Comment: There's not much point in editing the configuration *and* using symlinks.  Given the choice of editing the configuration *or* using symlinks, you should absolutely positively prefer the former (edit the configuration).  That said, yes, using symlinks as could complicate things and (again) is pointless.

Comment: Thank you. Does my configuration look right? Also I've accidentally deleted the /var/log directory. I did create one using sudo mkdir /var/log. But I see that Apache2 isn't able to access it. I think this is a permission issue. Could you tell me default permission of /var/log directory and how to set it?